# Spring Integration DSL: Simple way to send some messages to a Flow inputChannel

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

If I want to generate some sample data for testing purposes of the Spring Integration DSL functionality, one way I have come up with so far is like this:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow myFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Http.inboundChannelAdapter("numbers").get())
            .scatterGather(s -> s
                    .applySequence(true)
                    .recipientFlow(f -> f.handle((a, b) -> Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)))
            )
            .split() // unpack the wrapped list
            .split() // unpack the elements of the list
            .log()
            .get();
}
```

Is there another/better way to do the same thing ? Using the Scatter-Gather EIP seems like overkill for something so basic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simpler way of doing the same thing using `.transform()` instead of `.scatterGather()`

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow testFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Http.inboundChannelAdapter("test").get())
            .transform(t -> Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
            .split() // unpack the wrapped list
            .split() // unpack the elements of the list
            .get();
}
```

And here's another way you could do it using `.gateway()`

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow testFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Http.inboundChannelAdapter("test").get())
            .gateway(f -> f.handle((a, b) -> Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)))
            .split() // unpack the elements of the list
            .get();
}
```

And yet another:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow fromSupplier() {
    return IntegrationFlow.fromSupplier(() -> List.of(1,2,3,4), 
                    s -> s.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)))
            .log(Message::getPayload)
            .nullChannel();
}
```

Comment: Gateway is an overhead in this case. Anyway there is no treason to spawn the whole flow if what you just need is a message and channel from your main flow to send it

Answer (score 0):

You really can inject a specific `MessageChannel` from your flow to some testing component to send messages directly to that channel to be processed from the expecting endpoint in the flow. It is not clear what that scatter-gather does in your flow and where is the channel you talk in the title , but another way is to use a `@MessagingGateway` interface .

See more in docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#gateway

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-channels

Comment: In my example above I have created a simple flow with some sample data/messages (numbers from 1 to 10). This is a quick and dirty way to play around with Spring Integration DSL, because without messages/payloads you can't really do much :). I'm not clear yet from your response how I would do the same with the links you provided, or at least I'm suspecting it would be more work when what I'm looking for is a quick and simple way to get started with some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to get some test data injected into a flow:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow pollingFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlow
            .from(() -> new GenericMessage<>(List.of(1,2,3)),
                    e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(Duration.ofSeconds(1))))
            // do something here ever second
            .get();
}
```